# UITableView can't scroll while refreshing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Using Parse I am downloading images, text etc. and using them in table view cells. However, while refreshing (when the indicator is animating in the navigation bar) I cannot scroll or move on the app. It is as if the app has become unresponsive until the table view is done refreshing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you are downloading synchronously, which takes time, and thus you are blocking the interface. In real life, the WatchDog process will kill your app dead right before the user's eyes if you do that. Do some research; this question is all over Stack Overflow (and so are the solutions).

Comment: You should download your data in a background thread, if you perform these operations in the main thread, you block the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example on how to dispatch to a different thread, download the image and get back to main thread when the download is done.

```
func downloadImageAndUpdateUI(){
    imageView?.image = nil

    if let imageUrl = aValidUrl{
        //get image on another thread
        let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.rawValue)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0), {
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
            //get back to main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if imageUrl == self.requestedImageUrl { //making sure if this image is still needed (or if user havent moved on to something else)
                    if imageData != nil{
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like some of the comments already said, it's due to what's called "blocking the main thread". See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1) great tutorial to learn more about concurrency in Swift. The `WithBlock` or `InBackground` methods that you call on your Parse query should call it asynchronously. If for some reason you still have the issue, you should nest your Parse query inside a `dispatch_async` block. [Here's](https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/) a useful tutorial on how to do this.

Caution: **Always** do UI updating on your **main** thread. Bad things will happen if you don't.

Comment: This works, but it seems to take a very long time to load anything when using findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Should I just use Swift code?

Comment: If you're downloading images, then you're right, it will take a while, because you aren't refreshing the table view every time a new image downloads. In this case, you can work around this. Though it doesn't implement Parse, I learned through this video and I highly suggest it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyluPwsPZ8c. The principles will be the same.